# using customer session in block

Tags: blocks, magento2.3.5, view

I want to get customer id in block but the customer session returns null.

from controller, i could get customer id.

logger in block works well so the customer id is executed.

vendor/Block/Config.php

```
class Config extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template                                                                                                                                       
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->logger = $logger;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     */
    public function getCustomerId(): int
    {
        $this->logger->debug('this log is ok');
        return $this->session->getCustomer()->getId(); // return null
    }
```

from view,
`<?=$block->getCustomerId();?>`

this code returns 500 because the type hinting of getCustomerId() is :int and return null.

this->session->getCustomer returns null

this->session->isLoggedIn also returns null

i saw almost same, other question in stackexchange, they do not fit my ploblem.

like this [Magento2 error on injecting customer session in block](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96030/magento2-error-on-injecting-customer-session-in-block)

ofcourse i did

setup:upgrade

setup:di:compile

cache:celan

Comment: logger in block works well so the customer id is executed. -> logger in block works well so the getCustomerId() is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a Customer session if your page is at under **full-page cache**.

Use  `Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` in this case. See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html#configure-page-variations

Define a new `Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` variable   using a plugin on `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context:getVaryString` and set customer id to new varible. and after that get customer id from context

Answer (score 0):

> Create a plugin class on Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction.

**app/code/Vendorename/Modulename/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction">
        <plugin name="get_customr_id"  disabled="false" sortOrder="20" type="Vendorename\Modulename\Plugin\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction"/>
    </type>

    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendorename/Modulename/Plugin/Framework/App/Action**

**AbstractAction.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendorename\Modulename\Plugin\Framework\App\Action;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class AbstractAction
{

    private $customerRepository;
    private $customerSession;
    private $httpContext;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    public function aroundDispatch(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {

        $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomerId();
        $this->httpContext->setValue(
            'current_cust_id',
            $customerId,
            0
        );

        return $proceed($request);
    }
}
```

> After that adding above code ,add this \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context on your block class and get this customer id value by $this->httpContext->getValue('current_cust_id')

```
private $httpContext;

public function __construct(
    .........................................
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
    ............................................
) {
    .........................................
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    .........................................
}

.........................................


$cust_id = $this->httpContext->getValue('current_cust_id'); 
echo "Customer Id ".$cust_id;
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***